# Post multiple images with FastAPI and Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

I want to know how to use requests when use two image files as inputs.

server

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/images")
def images(img1: bytes = File(...), img2: bytes = File(...)):
    # **do something**
    return {"message": "OK"}
```

I succeded to post with `curl` command like below,

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/images' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'img1=@<IMG1_FILE>;type=image/<EXTENSION>' \
  -F 'img2=@<IMG2_FILE>;type=image/<EXTENSION>'
```

but I failed with scripts using requests like below, and got `400 BAD Request`

```py
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images"
headers = {"accept": "application/json", "content-type": "multipart/form-data"}
files = {"img1": open("img1_path.jpg", "rb"), "img2": open("img2_path.jpg", "rb")}

response = requests.post(url, headres=headers, files=files)
```

can anyone help me??

Comment: `headeres=headers` - did you mean `headers=headers`?

Comment: sorry this is typo, yes `headers=headers`

Comment: but the fixing typo doesn't matter whether fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ensure you installed `python-multipart` package.

Then Remove the `content-type` from request headers like below:

```py
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images"
headers = {"accept": "application/json"}
files = {"img1": open("img1_path.jpg", "rb"), "img2": open("img2_path.jpg", "rb")}

response = requests.post(url, headers=heaers, files=files)
```